# How to make a Delete Query inside a Trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am doing an after insert trigger on a table where I delete the rows that are incorrect, however, I am unable to do this and I can't find the correct syntax anywhere.

From what I understand, the table where the rows will be deleted from is in the `FROM` clause but I also need to use the inserted table. How do I do this?
I know this can be solved using an instead of insert trigger but I really want to know how to do this way.

```sql
DELETE 
FROM promotion p, inserted i 
WHERE <conditions>
```

Comment: `INSERTED` is not MySql syntax, have you TAGGED correctly?

Comment: Just join Inserted on your table (using an explicit join - not your old-school comma join) and delete from the alias of the table i.e. `p`. [Check example D in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE sometarget
FROM dbo.MyTable AS sometarget
JOIN inserted ON inserted.ID = sometarget.ID
WHERE <conditions>;
GO
```